# Show additional monthly field even if their is no data about them

Tags: mysql

I need to see the income in each month. So I ran this query:

```
SELECT 
    sum(project_cost), month(date_now)
FROM
    dentist.patient_info
WHERE
    year(date_now) = '2016'
GROUP BY month(date_now);
```

And the result was like the following:

[image]

What I really want, even if their is no data for months 1, 4, 5, 6 till 12, I need to display them into this result like:

```
0   || 1
250 || 2
...
```

Because I am going to send them into AJAX as a JSON array and display them in bar chart of **chartJS.**

Is their a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    sum(cost) as cost,
    month
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        sum(project_cost) as cost, 
        month(date_now) as month 
    FROM 
        dentist.patient_info 
    WHERE year(date_now)='2016' 
    GROUP BY month(date_now)

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        sum(payment), 
        month(date_now) 
    FROM 
        YOUR_TABLE_HERE
    WHERE year(date_now)='2016' 
    GROUP BY month(date_now)

    UNION SELECT 0,1
    UNION SELECT 0,2
    UNION SELECT 0,3
    UNION SELECT 0,4
    UNION SELECT 0,5
    UNION SELECT 0,6
    UNION SELECT 0,7
    UNION SELECT 0,8
    UNION SELECT 0,9
    UNION SELECT 0,10
    UNION SELECT 0,11
    UNION SELECT 0,12
) tmp
GROUP BY month
```

The unions simply add the missing months with 0 as cost, so the overall sum has all months.

Updated answer to include another `sum`. This assumes that your new table also has a `date_now` column similar to the one in `dentist.patient_info`

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Busted! I fixed it ;)

Comment: How to add inside of this query another `sum(payment) from another_table` and add the sum to the original one for each month ?

Comment: Before the `UNION SELECT 0,1 ...` add a `UNION SELECT sum(payment), month from another_table group by month`. Obviously, adapt this last query to what you need.

Comment: Nope, the value was 1100 and with new table should be 1550, but it showing me for the month number 3 value of 1950

Comment: Can you check exactly what the added query returns? The sum *should* be correct. Maybe that `where` needs an extra condition

Comment: can you help me more sir

Comment: Well, let's give it another try. So you're saying that the second query has added 850 to the sum of month 3 instead of 450? Please run that query alone and post the results here. This: `SELECT 
        sum(payment), 
        month(date_now) 
    FROM 
        YOUR_TABLE_HERE
    WHERE year(date_now)='2016' 
    GROUP BY month(date_now)`

Comment: what was the issue? out of curiosity

Comment: I was testing a different table

Comment: Instead of `debts` I added `outlay`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join` and `coalesce():

```
SELECT mon.mon, COALESCE(sum(project_cost), 0)
FROM (SELECT 1 as mon UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4 
      UNION ALL SELECT 5 
      UNION ALL SELECT 6 
      UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9 
      UNION ALL SELECT 10 
      UNION ALL SELECT 11 
      UNION ALL SELECT 12
     ) mon LEFT JOIN
     dentist.patient_info pi
     ON month(pi.date_now) = mon.mon
WHERE year(pi.date_now) = '2016'
GROUP BY mon.mon;
```

Comment: nope, it shows me only data for month 2 and 3. Others aren't on the list

Comment: @androidnation . . . The point of the `. . . ` was for the rest of the numbers that you need.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUM(project_cost), MONTH(date_now) FROM dentist.patient_info GROUP BY MONTH(date_now);

```
project_cost  |  date_now
100           |  2016-03-09
200           |  2016-02-01 
300           |  2016-02-16 
              |  2016-01-01
500           |  2016-02-02
              |  2016-04-01
288           |  2016-04-16
              |  2016-05-01
288           |  2016-05-16
```

I tried and It runs perfect.

It shows output like this

```
0             |  1
1000          |  2 
100           |  3
288           |  4
288           |  5
```